# YourKit: What does "objects which do not belong to particular web application" mean?

Tags: java, websphere, yourkit

In YourKit java profiler tool, in Web Application Category from Snapshot, there is recorded named

> objects which do not belong to particular web application

What does it mean if I use the WebSphere application server? who is the creator of its objects?

[image]

Comment: Someone had asked similar question on Yourkit forum: https://www.yourkit.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5328 . However, they further communicated on the personal mail. I think you can do the same.

Answer (score 0):

These objects cannot be attributed to a particular web application. They are not retained by a single web application, but are shared between multiple and/or belong to the server core, frameworks, etc.